# Ipad application - Access a java based web server

Tags: java, ios, ipad

I would like to create a native ipad application that displays data fetched from a webserver.  The application should be able to fetch tabular data, schedule things on the webserver and receive alerts

I suppose i could do the following

For fetching tabular data, use a single webservice call (will this work? what should be data interchange format? are there limitations to the data payload?)

For receiving alerts, would a persistent connection strategy work be the best way and are there better alternatives that i can tap into natively?

What remoting mechanisms are supported natively?

I have glassfish/spring setup.

Thanks

Comment: Be more specific? What are you tring to achieve?

Comment: I would like to display tabular data or be able to schedule some things on the webserver from the application. I'll edit the question to be more specific

Comment: Your question is very broad. Try narrowing it down by including a few details about the data, the fronted and backend, the application domain, anything. Without that info, we're stuck with guesswork as to what you're after.

Comment: This describes maybe half the ecosystem of iOS apps out there. Which at last count was half a million, so yea, at least you know its doable.

Comment: i've improved the question. but pls be patient as i'm new to this kind of an environment

Comment: what woud really help would be identification of the data your going to display, and how often it is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Having no idea of the data makes it hard to answer.*

A successful method applied by many is the web service method, with simple query when the app loads, or is used, and fall back to show data that was loaded last time it had a connection.

If the data is time sensitive, this is more of a dilema.

You could simply note the last refresh time. If your app will be used primarily in the office, this might suffice.

Having a refresh button is a must.

The only reason to think about a persistent connection is if you want some form of server push.  That is, do you need the server to inform the device of updates.  Use cases for this are things like "chat".

Otherwise a timer asking for updates from the server is the way to go, since it is SO much easier to develop.

Comment: the data is not time critical per-se and will be utilized for viewing/ making adjustments to it.

Comment: So web services is the way to go, and cache the data in the app/ on the ipad.  That would be teh best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Apples toolbox supplies NSUrlConnection

Answer (score 1):

Your iPad app and your web server would have to be very loosely coupled.

Your question is very broad at the moment. While you go, other question will arise.

One pointer though: You must find an exchange protocol that suits your needs (e. g. JSON) and implement this on both sides. The choice depends on your experience and the data you want to exchange.